# Chat to original IP via VPN encrypted?

Tags: encryption, vpn

**Background**

I wrote a small server and client for a unencrypted chat in java. 
I now wanted to make the communication between the server application and the client application encrypted.

**So i thought the following might work but i'm not sure about it:**

If I do the following steps, will the traffic between the server and the client be encrypted?

1. Activate a VPN on the computer where i also start the server application
2. Start the Client Application on another computer
3. connect the Client to the Server by connecting to the "real" IP adress and
   a port of the Computer where the server is running, but not the IP it has   cause of the VPN

The VPN blocks all traffic outside of this connection. So the client has to connect via the VPN connection was what i thought.

Comment: I tried to edit this question but truthfully I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.

Comment: You're asking if you turn on your VPN whether someone can connect to your real IP and not the VPN IP still, correct?

Comment: Yep, and if this is working, does anyone who wants to connect to my real IP getting tunneled through the VPN. Cause in this way, the communication would be encrypted via the VPNs traffic

Comment: why not use the many available Java libraries to encrypt the connection?

Answer (score 3):

If your computer is a VPN client and another computer tries to connect to it without going through the VPN, it will not be encrypted unless your application does its own encryption.

Comment: Is there a possibility to send the traffic through the VPN ? I dont know if theres an open port i can use for that...